# How to reduce size when building from source

Tags: drake

The bazel build is 90gb. I just want to use the commercial solvers. Is there any way to reduce build size?

Comment: What command are you using to build?  My recollection is that a `cmake && make install` is not 90 GB of space, though I haven't run it recently.  Looking at [recent ci](https://drake-jenkins.csail.mit.edu/view/Linux%20Focal/job/linux-focal-gcc-cmake-continuous-release) it seems to take only 3 GB.

Comment: I am using the instructions telling us to use bazel here: https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html#developing-drake-using-bazel

Comment: So you are saying we don't need to use bazel? And after downloading drake from github, we just go into the root and do the cmake command you said?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html near "Building the Python Bindings".  The section title is misleading: it works for building all of Drake, not just the Python bindings.

The docs should do a better job of showing the GUROBI settings, though.

Here's a working example:

```
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
env GUROBI_HOME=/path/to/Downloads/gurobi951/linux64 \
  cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=ON \
    ../drake
make install
```

The install ends up in `drake-build/install` by default.

If you'd like to build Drake as an external in your existing CMakeLists project, see also [drake-external-examples/drake_cmake_external](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_cmake_external).

Comment: What about MOSEK? Do we set MOSEK_HOME?

Comment: Just the `-DWITH_MOSEK=ON` should be enough to build with MOSEK.  Drake will download MOSEK on its own.